# Remove TreeMap entries less than x

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

**I have the following TreeMap:**

```
private Map<Date,WeekSchedule> weeks = new TreeMap<Date,WeekSchedule>();
```

**And I need to remove all entries, whose date is before a given value.**

What is the most efficient way to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
public void removeWeeksBefore(Date monDate){
    for (Map.Entry<Date, WeekSchedule> entry : weeks.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getKey().before(monDate)){
            weeks.remove(entry.getKey());   //This will destroy the iterator
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Date` comparable?  Can you store this as a `NavigableMap`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, `Java.util.Date` is compareable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most *efficient* way is probably storing this as a `SortedMap` and then using the one line

```
map.headMap(monDate).clear();
```

Comment: You could store it as `TreeMap`, sure, but the OP stored it as a `Map`, which doesn't support `headMap`.  The performance is going to depend on the implementation, and there are certainly tree implementations which could support this in `O(log n)`; I can readily believe that the _current_ implementation doesn't support this faster, though.  I don't know why you'd expect iterating to be more efficient in memory, though, and I absolutely do claim that this is specifically intended as a way to use the `SortedMap` view types and the intended solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't care about the map values, you only need to iterate over the [`keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29):

```
Iterator<Date> iter = weeks.keySet().iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next().before(monDate))
        iter.remove();
    else
        return;  // since TreeMap is sorted by key
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason, why you removed the return-statement in the else-branch?

Comment: @maja Because we don't want to return as soon as we find an element that doesn't need to be removed. We want to traverse the *entire* map.

Comment: Yes, by natural order.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Good point, I forgot we were dealing with a `TreeMap`. I guess we can use `return` after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iterator instead of for-each loop, if you are modifying the `Iterable`.

```
    for (Iterator<Entry<Date, WeekSchedule>> i = weeks.entrySet().iterator() ; i.hasNext(); ){
        Entry<Date, WeekSchedule> entry = i.next();
        if(entry.getKey().before(monDate)){
            i.remove();
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
```